# Multiple concurrent operation Exception is thrown when using nested Query Extension

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I would like to make Query Extension that maps database models to view models, but I would also like to reuse them for relationship models.

Customer entity has property

```
public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

And mapping is done with Query Extensions

```
var viewModelList = dbContext.Customers
                .Include(a => a.Orders)
                .ToCustomersModel()
                .ToList();


public static IQueryable<CustomersModel> ToCustomersModel(this IQueryable<Customer> query)
{
    return query.Select(customer => new CustomersModel
                        {
                            Id = customer.Id,
                            Name = customer.Name,
                            Orders = customer.Orders.AsQueryable().ToOrdersModel().ToList()
                        });
}

public static IQueryable<OrdersModel> ToOrdersModel(this IQueryable<Order> query)
{
    return query.Select(customer => new OrdersModel
                        {
                            Id = order.Id,
                            ProductName = order.ProductName
                        });
```

It throws exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation started on this
>   context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members
>   are not guaranteed to be thread safe.'

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.1 and .net Core 2.1

Comment: Yes, you are starting a 2nd query.

Comment: Is there any way I could accomplish this without starting second query

Answer (score 0):

What if you do not need call the Iqueryable method

```
var viewModelList = dbContext.Customers
                .Include(a => a.Orders)
                .ToCustomersModel()
                .ToList();


public static IQueryable<CustomersModel> ToCustomersModel(this IQueryable<Customer> query)
{
    return query.Select(customer => new CustomersModel
                        {
                            Id = customer.Id,
                            Name = customer.Name,
                            Orders = customer.Orders.ToList().Select(customer => new OrdersModel
                                                           {
                                                               Id = order.Id,
                                                               ProductName = order.ProductName
                                                           }).ToList()
                        });
}
```